# OpenERP onChange event selection

Tags: python, selection, field, odoo

I'm trying to detect the event onchange from a selection field.

```
def onchange_changeday(self, cr, uid, ids, day_type, context=None):
    if day_type == "Complete":
        x = "09:00"
        return {'value':{'hour_begin': x }}

_columns = {
        'hour_begin':fields.char("Hour", size = 20),
        'day_type':fields.selection([('Complete', 'Complete'), ('Noncomplete', 'NonComplete')])
}
```

And then in the XML view I have:

```
<field name="hour_begin" placeholder="00:00" class="oe_inline_hour"/>
<field name="day_type" on_change="onchange_changeday(day_type, context)"/>
```

The goal was to whenever I change the selection to "Complete" it completes the field "hour_begin" with the value "09:00". I don't receive any errors, but it's not working either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
 def onchange_changeday(self, cr, uid, ids, day_type, context=None):
        if day_type:
            x = day_type
            if x == "Complete":
                  return {'value':{'hour_begin': '09:00',},}
        return {'value': {}}

<field name="day_type" on_change="onchange_changeday(day_type, context)"/>
```